# Using curl within a Databricks+Spark notebook

Tags: curl, apache-spark, databricks

I'm running a Spark cluster using Databricks. I'd like to transfer data from a server using curl. For example,

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "auth:xxxx" -X GET "https://websites.net/Automation/Offline?startTimeInclusive=201609240100&endTimeExclusive=201609240200&dataFormat=json" -k > automation.json
```

How does one do this within a Databricks notebook (preferably in python, but Scala is also okay)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala, you can do something like:

```
import sys.process._
val command = """curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "auth:xxxx" -X GET "http://google.com" -k > /home/user/automation.json"""
Seq("/bin/bash", "-c", command).!!
```

Comment: Where in the dbfs is the file saved? I tried -k > /tmp/automation.json, but can't location the file.

Comment: I haven't tested it in exactly the databricks environment, but I don't see any why if that call returns successfully, you shouldn't be able to access the file at the location you have mentioned.

Comment: Using -k > /dbfs/automation.json appears to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In Databricks, you can run a shell command from a cell by making %sh the first line of the cell:

```
%sh
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "auth:xxxx" -X GET "https://websites.net/Automation/Offline?startTimeInclusive=201609240100&endTimeExclusive=201609240200&dataFormat=json" -k > automation.json
```